# Spring Boot - How to read application.properties in custom sequence generator which used in @GenericGenerator

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, properties-file, sequence-generators

I created a CustomSequenceGenerator for my model, everything is working fine.

Now i'm trying to read value from application.properties inside the CustomSequenceGenerator but failed.

I have tried many ways suggested by stackoverflow but still no luck on this.

```
1. Using @Value
2. Using Spring Environment env > env.getProperty()
3. Using @ConfigurationProperties
4. Using @PropertySource
```

Here is my codes:

**Model**

```
  @Id
  @GenericGenerator(name = "user_id_gen", strategy="com.my.model.common.CustomSequenceGenerator ",
          parameters = {
                  @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "sequence_name", value = "USER_SEQ")}
  )
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "user_id_gen")
  @Column(name = "UserId", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 6)
  private String userId;
```

**CustomSequenceGenerator**

```
public class CustomSequenceGenerator implements IdentifierGenerator, Configurable {

    @Value("${seq.prefix}")
    private String sequencePrefix;

    .......
}
```

I put a break point on my CustomSequenceGenerator and i noticed that it jumps into the break point during server startup, so i guess that spring is not able to read the application.properties during startup/initialization.

**application.properties**

located in `Resources/conf/application.properties`, I have specify the location using `-Dspring.config.location` and other controllers have no problem in accessing the properties file, just CustomSequenceGenerator is having issue.

```
....
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
seq.prefix = MOCKDB.MOCK_SCHEMA.
....
```

So how can i read the properties value in this case ?

Thank you.

Comment: Please show application.properties as well

Answer (score 1):

You can use [System Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) to pass your value from application.properties

```
   @Component
    public class PropertiesConfig {
    
        @Value("${z.prefix}")
        private String zPrefix;
    
        @PostConstruct
        public void setProperty() {
            System.setProperty("z.prefix", zPrefix);
        }
    }
```

And then read it in your custom generator

```
var zPrefix = System.getProperty("z.prefix");
```